How to make the clamped attachment move in two directions?
In the below attached image link, I would like to move the clamped attachment (clamps shown in yellow color), in two directions (shown by red arrows). What kind of motor and joint arrangements should I make to achieve this?
 My mechanical assembly 
I was looking into rotary joints to make this assembly, however rotary joints do not make the two clamps rotate "synchronously" in either direction.
Are there "motorized rotary joints available", which can rotate the two clamps synchronously in the given direction?
I am looking for some pointers.

please add the image directly into your post

https://kingfisher.scene7.com/is/image/Kingfisher/6411501147905_02bq

Thank you @jsotola. I got the idea. However, I am not able to add an image directly into the post. The portal allows me to add a jpg. But when I previewed it, I got to see a "generic image icon".  (Just FYI, I am trying to preview the image uploaded on my google drive.)
